# WinJS : Returning promise from a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, winjs, winjs-promise

I would like to make a function that returns a promise. That promise would contain the data of an asynchronous call made in the function. What I want it to look like :

```
//Function that do asynchronous work
function f1() {
    var url = ...
    WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(
    function completed(request) {
        var data = ...processing the request...
        ...
    },
    function error(request) {
        ...
    });
}

//Code that would use the result of the asynchronous function
f1().done(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

The only way I found to make this work is to pass a callback to f1 and call it when I have the data. Using callbacks though seems to defeat the goal achieved by promises. Is there a way to make it work like above? Also, I could return WinJS.xhr in f1, but the done method of f1 would return the request and not the "data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little to change:

```
function f1() {
    var url = …;
    return WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(function completed(request) {
//  ^^^^^^
        var data = …; // processing the request
        return data;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
}

//Code that would use the result of the asynchronous function
f1().done(function(data) {
    …
}, function error(request) {
    … // better handle errors in the end
});
```

You don't want to return the `WinJS.xhr()` itself indeed, but you want to return the result of the `.then(…)` call which is exactly the promise that resolves with the return value of the callback. This is one of [the main features of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) :-)